# Formula hub - fixed cone on the axle

Tags: hub, bearings, racing

Does anybody have the diagram for a generic Formula hub axle assembly? It has a fixed cone on one side of the axe with no spanner flats. I'm not sure which side of the hub this is supposed to go on and am having trouble with the disk brake spacing in the frame. Bike is an ~ 2006-7 Felt with disk brakes.

Comment: If you are having trouble aligning the rotor presumably you are not centering the wheel in the frame properly either. Any reason a spacer cannot go outside the fixed cone?